# set style and input event for tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce

- how to set `border` and `border-radius` for tinymce editor
- how to set `input` event for the editor

here is my try - without success:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "#ed",
autoresize_bottom_margin : 5,
menubar: false,
branding: false,
resize: false,
statusbar: false,
editor_css: "style.css",
plugins: ["lists hr"],
toolbar: false
});
```

**style.css**

```
#ed{
    background:#ddd; // doesn't work        
    border:2px solid #aaa; // doesn't work
    border-radius:14px; // doesn't work
    min-height:54vh; // works
}
```

**js**

```
var ed = $('#ed');
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor; // also tried
ed.on('input', function(){
    console.log('lorem'); // doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to get the selectors in pure js, not by jquery.

To get the input use the snippet below.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
        editor.on('input', function(input){
            //console.log('Element input', input); // get all
            console.log('Element input', input.rangeParent); // get rangeParent
        });
        
    },
        
    // ...
});
```

tinymce events:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/advanced/events/

Comment: works fine, thanks a lot. any idea about css, pls

Comment: http://skin.tiny.cloud/t4/ and http://skin.tiny.cloud/t5/ you can create custum skins